# Why the margin of the first elements are not the same(*, 0) when horizontal scrolling? UWP muxc:ItemRepeater

Tags: c#, uwp, user-controls

I previously ran UWP code like this:

in repeater page

```xml
<muxc:ItemsRepeaterScrollHost Grid.Row="1">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <muxc:ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}">
            <muxc:ItemsRepeater.Layout>
                <muxc:StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="8" />
            </muxc:ItemsRepeater.Layout>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="item:RepoListItem">
                <Grid>
                    <block:RepoButtonBlock
                                        x:Name="RepositoryBlock"
                                        Width="250"
                                        Height="{Binding ScrollViewer.Height}"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        DisplayStarButton="False"
                                        RepositoryId="{x:Bind RepoId, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </muxc:ItemsRepeater>
    </ScrollViewer>
</muxc:ItemsRepeaterScrollHost>
```

ViewModel.Items:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<RepoListItem> PinnedRepos { get; private set; } = new();
```

RepoListItem:

```cs
    public class RepoListItem
    {
        public long RepoId { get; set; }

        public Repository Repository { get; set; }
    }
```

block:RepoButtonBlock user control

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Button
            x:Name="RepoBlockButton"
            Margin="0,3,0,0"
            Padding="18,12"
            Click="RepoBlockButton_Click"
            Style="{StaticResource ContentBlockButtonStyle}">
            ....
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

The height of the `block:RepoButtonBlock` varies depending on the control inside the button. I set VerticalAlignment to Stretch because it scrolls horizontally and must be the same height. However, only the first repeater that scrolls and disappears will have the element height reduced to its actual size and fixed below. I have any idea. Is there solution to this problem?

before scrolling:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsXPJ.png

scrolled to the end:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/spxIV.png

back to the first elem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO777.png

Comment: Please share a [mcve] here instead of your full project. Or you could attach more code to your question so that we could create a sample using the code you share.  That will be helpful to locate your issue. Please do not post your full project.

Comment: ok. sorry done.

Comment: Could you please share an example about the `ViewModel.Items` that you used as a data source with us?

Comment: yes. reuploaded!

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue based on the code you posted. But I just use a simple button without style. The `ItemsRepeater` with buttons does not show the behavior you mentioned. Could you please share enough code that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: The code involved in presenting this code is so vast that it is impossible to present a portion of it. Therefore, I fixed the height and set TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" to the TextBlock in the UserControl. so I fixed partially. I'm sorry but thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code involved in presenting this code is so vast that it is impossible to present a portion of it.

Therefore, I fixed the height and set `TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"` to the TextBlock in the UserControl. so I fixed partially.